# Calling .jar from shell script

Tags: java, oracle, shell, encryption, jar

I have a shell script which calls a .jar file.Following is the command:

```
java -Xms256m -Xmx512m -cp (path)/VxCryptor.jar

com.datalog.security.PrepareImportFile $SOURCE_FILE $TARGET_FILE -f

(path)/$ENCRYPTION_KEY
```

It gives the following error:

**Error:** Could not find or load main class com.datalog.security.PrepareImportFile

Can you tell me what does this command do? and what is this Error about?

Comment: Are you giving the full path (starting with a `/`), or a relative path; which might not still be valid by the time you use it in the script? Or if `(path)` is a variable is it set in the script or the shell, and if the latter is it exported? Are the permissions correct on the `.jar` file?

Comment: yes i am giving full path (starting with /) and the .jar has all the permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command runs a java class located in a jar file with the given parameters.

`-Xms256m/-Xmx512m`:    Minimum/Maximum memory heap sizes available to your JVM, here 256m/512m.

`-cp x/y/z/VxCryptor.jar`:   Classpath(s) of your classes/jar file(s).

`com.datalog.security.PrepareImportFile`:   The fully qualified name of the class containing a `main(String[] args)` method that you want to run.

The rest are parameters passed to `com.datalog.security.PrepareImportFile.main`.

The error tells you that no such class could be found in the given jar. **However, note that java will say the same if no such jar exists at the given classpath**.

Check:

1. The classpath
2. The fully qualified class name, i.e., check that the package is correct.
3. Do `jar -tf VxCryptor.jar` to display/check the content of your jar file.

Comment: The Jar File is present at the location.

Comment: Can you do `jar -tf VxCryptor.jar` to display the content of your jar file? That way you'll see if your fully qualified package name is correct.

Comment: Its giving error.

java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

Comment: Then your jar file is corrupted. Where/how did you get it?

Comment: Yes the jar is not opening, its showing corrupted jar..Is there any way to open that corrupted file?

Comment: It could really be anything. I wouldn't venture down that path. Do you know who made the jar? As such, this jar is useless.

Comment: Yes Got the new File as that was corrupted